# E-Commerce analytics in opencart

Tags: opencart

I want to product information on google eCommerce analytics. 
How to add google eCommerce analytics code in Open Cart project and show product details in eCommerce analytics

Answer (score 0):

Search the marketplace and find an extension:
https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension&filter_search=ecommerce%20analytics